# How to reference an AppIcon which is under a folder in an AssetCatalog

Tags: ios, xcode6

The thing is that I have more AppIcons and I want to have them organized under a folder in the Images.xcassets AssetCatalog, not just have them in the root folder.

I was able to create them properly, I just cannot enter a valid value in t he Target's Build Setting under

Asset Catalog Compiler - Options -> Asset Catalog App Icon Set Name.

E.g.: I have the following AppIcons:

- AppIconDev
- AppIconAdHoc

They are placed under the folder **AppIcons** in the **Images.xcassets** catalog.
I have provided the following value in the above mentioned part of the Build Settings:

**AppIcons/AppIconDev**

And the build is failing with the following error message:
/.../xcode/ProjectDir/ProjectName/Images.xcassets: None of the input catalogs contained a matching app icon set named  "AppIcons/AppIconDev".